# How override the AMP URL mode from Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Can i replace default URL AMP to another pattern?

Example:
?amp=1 > /amp/

Next.Js doc:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/amp

> The page is rendered as traditional HTML (default) and AMP HTML (by adding ?amp=1 to the URL)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any existing feature for this in next js, but what you can do is to make it yourself using the file system routing by adding your pages in `/amp` folder :

- pages/index.js
- pages/amp/index.js

The amp pages just reexport the content of their equivalent pages :

```
// /amp/index.js
import Page, { getStaticProps } from "../index";

export const config = { amp: true };
export default Page;
export { getStaticProps };
```

The pages that are not amp are standard pages, but don't forget to link to the amp pages :

```
export config = {}

export default Page(){
  const isAmp = useAmp();
  return (
  <>
      {isAmp ? (
        <Head>
          <link rel="canonical" href="/" />
        </Head>
      ) : (
        <Head>
          <link rel="amphtml" href="/amp" />
        </Head>
      )}
      <div>Home Page</div>

  </>)
}
```